# How to conditionally add key to json if it doesn't exist?

Tags: json, windows, key, jq

**I  have a json file with the following data:**

```
{
  "Index" : {
    "example_user" : {
      "important_key" : "leave_me_alone",
      "blah" : {
        "more_stuff" : {
          "ignore_this" : "and_this_too"
        }
      }
    },
    "another_user" : {
      "blah" : {
        "more_stuff" : {
          "ignore_this" : "and_this_too"
        }
      }
    },
    "extra_person" : {
      "blah" : {
        "more_stuff" : {
          "ignore_this" : "and_this_too"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `important_key` is missing from `another_user` and `extra_person`.

My goal is to conditionally add `"imporant_key" : ""` where it is missing but ***not*** replace any *existing* `important_key` values. The program i use is `JQ` (1.6) from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/.

After many failed attempts on `jqplay.org` and having intensively (re)searched the internet on how to get the job done , i've only managed to realize the following:

**Filter**:`.Index[]+={"important_key":"data"}`

**Result**

```
{
  "Index": {
    "example_user": {
      "important_key": "data",
      "blah": {
        "more_stuff": {
          "ignore_this": "and_this_too"
        }
      }
    },
    "another_user": {
      "blah": {
        "more_stuff": {
          "ignore_this": "and_this_too"
        }
      },
      "important_key": "data"
    },
    "extra_person": {
      "blah": {
        "more_stuff": {
          "ignore_this": "and_this_too"
        }
      },
      "important_key": "data"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm aware `+=` (over)writes any existing key value (note `example_user`). I've been experimenting with multiple `piped` filters/operators, including `|=` and `{` `}`, but in the end, the above result was the closest i could get.

(unfortunately i can't seem to find the jqplay code snippet where i went "crazy" with everything)

Comment: The following command line using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) would work for this example. `jrepl.bat "{(\s*)(\x22blah\x22)" "{$1\x22important_key\x22: \x22\x22,$1$2" /M /X /F "Example.json" /O -` Let me know if you are happy with that solution although not using __jq__ and I can write an answer and explain the JScript regular expression which is quite simple. Regular expression questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know dbenham's excellent JREPL script (i can't seem to format the text here), but since there are working examples for arrays in json, i was (and am) hoping this can be done using JQ, alone. I appreciate your input though, that's why i'll upvote your comment. In the meantime i'll continue hoping for a JQ type of approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you have to conditionally do something, you have to do some sort of filtering, either using `if` or `select` or other means.

For every object you wish to inspect, check if the object has your `important_key` and add it when necessary. If it has the key, do nothing, otherwise set it.

```
.Index[] |= if has("important_key") then . else .important_key = $myImportantKey end
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Jeff Mercado. I've been using those statements a lot in cmd/batch and C projects but JQ (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a whole different story for me. As $myImportantKey is a custom variable/value, how would i transform this to make it usable on jqplay.org (thus also with JQ)?

Comment: `$myImportantKey` is just some (jq) variable that has the value you wish to set. It doesn't necessarily have to be a variable, you could just insert whatever you wish in its place. Here's all of this in a jqplay snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/eIFpsS15Ii

Comment: Jeff, you did it? I think i have to comprehend this magic of yours... Please give me some time to re(adapt/adjust) my inner workings and i'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: If it was in my power i would give you a GOLD badge, but that would be considered cheating, so i'll just select your answer as solution! This really made my week :-) (additional JQ answers are still welcome and appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that still works for jq v1.6; without needing an if statement.

```
.Index[] |= { "important_key":  "data" } + .
```

Will set the default `important_key` to `"data"` if the key does not exist. It will keep any values set as any other values, including `null`.

Explanation:

`.index[] |=`  replaces every entry with the result of the expression

`{ "important_key": "data" } + .` is an object where we set the default value(s), then shallow merge `+` with the existing object at the current selected scope `.`

For a deep merge use `*` instead of `+`

*(Ammending this solution due to its search ranking for terms like "update jq object if field doesn't exist")*